# fade toggle jquery

Tags: html, jquery, toggle, transição

Tenho uma div e dentro dela um header (h3) e um button, quero que quando eu pressione esse button, altere o conteúdo do texto e do button, com um novo texto e um novo button com um efeito fadeOut para o texto/button atual e FadeIn pro novo texto/button! como posso fazer isso ?

```
<div class"h1 text">
<h3 class="ui header">O texto a ser alternado</h3>
<button class="ui button">button</button
</div>
```

Comment: Ao invés de descrever seu html seria melhor incluir no conteúdo da pergunta.

Comment: "Tenho uma div" ok poste para podermos ajudar .

Comment: codigo adicionado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar `fadeOut` com *callback* alterando os textos dos elementos e finalizando com `fadeIn`.

Veja que selecionei o `H3` em `.find("h3")` e em seguida o `button` com `.next()`, já que o `button` é o próximo elemento após o `H3`:

```js
$(".ui.button").click(function(){
   $(this).closest("div").fadeOut( function(){
      // troca o texto do H3 e o texto do button
      // e faz fadeIn
      $(this)
      .closest("div")
      .fadeIn()
      .find("h3")
      .text("Novo texto no H3")
      .next()
      .text("novo texto do button");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class"h1 text">
   <h3 class="ui header">O texto a ser alternado</h3>
   <button class="ui button">button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo lúdico utilizando Jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var contador = 0;
  $("#botao").on('click', function(){
    contador++;
    $(this).val("Yay!");    
    
    $("#texto").fadeOut(function(){ 
      $("#botao").fadeOut();
      
      $(this).html(contador + " cliques e contando..").fadeIn(function(){
          $("#botao").val("Clique").fadeIn();
      });  
      
    });
                  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Tenho uma div e dentro dela um header (h3) e um button, quero que quando eu pressione esse button, altere o conteúdo do texto e do button, com um novo texto e um novo button com um efeito fadeOut para o texto/button atual e FadeIn pro novo texto/button! como posso fazer isso ? -->

<div>
  <h3 id="texto">Contador de clicks</h3>
  <input id="botao" type="button" value="Clique">
</div>
```